# In 3 rooms upstairs electric outlets stopped working but overhead lights work - any idea

Tags: electrical

In 3 rooms upstairs electric outlets stopped working but overhead lights work - any idea
I reset all breakers still same problem
Then to make things weirder, is that the outlets will start working again, only to shut off.
There doesn't seem to be any cycle to how long on/off.
No A/C are on.  Otherwise standard equipment in the house (frig, freezer, TVs, computers) nothing too heavy

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the non-working outlets on the same breaker? Are the lights on the same breaker as the outlets, or on a different breaker?

Comment: yep, just checked, they're all on the same breaker.

Comment: Also, found that the boiler is on the same breaker too

Comment: Where are you on this planet, by the way?

Comment: Probably a loose connection on a back-stab outlet. Are there any outlets on the circuit that ARE working? If so, try pulling the "last" one (if possible to determine) with the power off of course and check it. Best practice is to pig tail all the connections and not rely on the outlet itself for continuity to the downstream outlets.

Comment: FYI - I'm from NY